# Inner Join Statement in SQLite with Conditions

Tags: sql, join, sqlite, inner-join

If we have the following two tables, "teachers" and "classes", how do we use an INNER JOIN statement to produce the final table where (i) "class_count" must be at least 2 for a teacher to be included in the final table and (ii) the "rating" of a class must be at least 50 for a class to count in the "average_rating" calculation?

"teachers" table

```
teachers

class_id    teacher_id    teacher_name    class_count
1111        1234          Smith           2
4444        2345          Jones           3
2222        1234          Smith           2
5555        2345          Jones           3
3333        5678          Taylor          2
6666        2345          Jones           3
7777        5678          Taylor          2
8888        6789          Thomas          1
```

"classes" table

```
classes

id        class_name      rating
1111      Math            60
2222      Biology         70
3333      Psychology      50
4444      Physics         80
5555      Chemistry       30
6666      Economics       60
7777      Computing       70
8888      Statistics      90
```

And we want the final table to look like:

```
teacher_id      teacher_name     average_rating
1234            Smith            65           
2345            Jones            70            
5678            Taylor           60
```

I tried the following code in sqlite but it did not give the correct result (as found in the final table above).

```
SELECT t.teacher_id, t.teacher_name, SUM(c.rating) / t.class_count
FROM teachers t
INNER JOIN classes c on c.id = t.class_id
WHERE c.rating >= 50 AND t.class_count >= 2;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "did not work"? Are you getting an error? The wrong result?

Comment: Getting the wrong result

Comment: Care to share it?

Comment: Hi. When you researched re SUM you came across GROUP BY. How did exploring it go? What parts can you do using it? Why don't you mention it? Please read & act on hits googling 'stackexchange homework'. Also: This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. Also [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you only miss a `GROUP BY` clause.

Join the tables on the ID of the class. In a `WHERE` clause filter for the desired `class_count` and `rating`. Then `GROUP BY` the ID and name of the teacher and use you sum by count expression to calculate the average rating.

```
SELECT t.teacher_id,
       t.teacher_name,
       sum(t.rating) / t.class_count average_rating
       FROM teachers t
            INNER JOIN classes c
                       ON c.id = t.class_id
       WHERE t.class_count >= 2
             AND t.rating >= 50
       GROUP BY t.teacher_id,
                t.teacher_name;
```

But your schema is not the best.

Instead of repeating the teachers for every class they teach, there should only be one row per teacher in the `teachers` table.

Which teacher teaches which class should be stored in a linking table containing the ID of the class and the ID of the teacher.

Also the count of classes a teacher teaches can be queried. It shouldn't be physically stored in the `teachers` table, as this requires the value to be updated whenever there is a change to the classes a teacher teaches. It's also dangerous, if such an update is forgotten or failed, that the value is just wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is the correct answer. Well you almost got it - just missed two things:
first there is no GROUP BY (you have to include this statement ALWAYS with the agregate functions, and then there is field class_count - but you have to calculate average rating from the SUM of ratings divided with the number of classes ( COUNT(*) ).

So if the results you put at the end of your question is correct, then the code bellow is also correct.

```
SELECT 
    t.teacher_id, 
    t.teacher_name, 
    SUM(c.rating) / COUNT(*) as average_rating

FROM teachers t

INNER JOIN classes c on 
    c.id = t.class_id

WHERE
    t.class_count >= 2 and
    c.rating >= 50

GROUP BY
    t.teacher_id, 
    t.teacher_name

ORDER BY
    t.teacher_id
```

--Result:

```
teacher_id  teacher_name    average_rating
1234        Smith           65.000000
2345        Jones           70.000000
5678        Taylor          60.000000
```